# Is it possible to access Chrome data without root?

Tags: root-access, chrome-for-android

I have a OnePlus 5T. Android version 9. OxygenOS version 9.0.5.

Is it possible to access the `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs/0` folder without root privileges?
As I understood, rooting will wipe out the data on the device.

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIR Chrome is an app that defines `allowBackup=false`, therefore without root there is no way to access the app private data. In general the "rooting" step is not the one that deletes the data, that is caused by the "bootloader unlock" step. However usually unlocking the bootloader is a requirement for rooting.

Answer (score 1):

App data folders of **any** app cannot be accessed without root. Even ADB has limited power here

On top of that, in some versions of Chrome on Android app data is encrypted